# Quitar elementos admin menu wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Estoy intentando quitar elementos del menú admin en wordpress para un usuario específico con la siguiente función:

```
    function remove_menus() {
      global $menu;
      global $submenu;
      if ( wp_get_current_user()->ID == 5 ) {
      remove_menu_page( 'themes.php' );
      }
    }

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menus' );
```

pero esta simplemente la oculta es decir si el usuario va a la url directamente puede acceder ¿hay alguna forma de bloquear la url también?

Como alternativa hago  una redirección si el usuario accede a la url

```
function profile_redirect() {
  if ( wp_get_current_user()->ID == 5 ) {
  $result = stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'themes.php');
  if ($result!==false) {
    wp_redirect(get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-admin/index.php');
  }
}
}
```

pero ¿como puedo agregar en la misma línea donde declaro la variable $ result mas paginas ademas de themes.php?

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión, cambiaría esa lógica. Lo que haría sería manejarlo con roles de usuario, me parece más lógico.
Haría algo así.

```
    if( is_admin() ) {
    add_filter( 'init', 'custom_restrict_pages_from_admin' );
}

function custom_restrict_pages_from_admin() {
    global $pagenow;

    $arr = array(
        'update-core.php',
        'edit.php'
    );

    if( custom_check_user_roles() && in_array( $arr , $pagenow ) ) {
        //echo some custom messages or call the functions 
    } else {
        echo 'This page has restricted access to specific roles';
        wp_die();
    }
}

function custom_check_user_roles() {
    //restrict pages by user role 

    if( current_user_can( 'administrator' ) || current_user_can( 'editor' ) ) 
         return true;
    else { 
        echo 'Not allowed!'; 
        wp_die();
    }
}
```